If $n$-th Homology is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, then $M$ is Orientable
I apologize if this has been asked before, but I could not find a reference. It is known if $M$ is an orientable connected $n$-manifold (without boundary), then $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Is the converse also true assuming $M$ is connected? That is, if $M$ is connected $n$-manifold with $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$, is it true that $M$ is orientable?

What is the converse? Do you assume that M is a n manifold ?

@julio_es_sui_glace yes, assuming $M$ is connected $n$-manifold. Let me edit it to make it more clear

You have to assume that $M$ is compact, for the known fact. E.g. $\mathbb R^2$ is orientable, but $H_2(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb Z)=0$.

@red_trumpet ah I see. If I change to relative homology $H_n(M,M\backslash{x};\mathbb{Z})$, would that still be the same?

No. By excision, that holds for every $n$-dimensional manifold. I’m not sure what “that” you are referring to.

@TedShifrin I see, I meant the conclusion.

If $M$ is a non-orientable compact connected $n$-manifold with $\partial M = \emptyset$, by Hatcher, Algebraic Topology Theorem $3.26$ part $b)$ it is $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}) \to H_n(M, M\setminus \{x\};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ injective for all $x \in M$ with image $\{n \in \mathbb{Z} \ | \ 2n = 0\} = \{0\}$. This means $H_n(M,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$.
If $M$ is not compact it is always $H_n(M; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ (for $n > 0$).  This is Proposition $3.29$ in Hatcher, Algebraic Topology.
In particular it holds: if $M$ is connected and $H_n(M; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ then $M$ is compact and orientable.

Thank you. If I change to relative homology, as you pointed out, without compactness, is it true that we can have $H_n(M,M\backslash{x};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ for some non-orientable $n$-manifold?

@LaurencePW For every $n$-manifold it is $H_n(M, M \setminus {x}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ by exicision and because $M$ is locally euclidean and the fact that  $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus {x}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Thus local orientations always exists (generators of this group).

I agree for local, what happens with global orientation? For example $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is not orientable for evern $n$ because its $n$-th homology group is $0$. I am wondering the $n$-th homology group is $\mathbb{Z}$ whether it's still true or not the manifold is globally orientable

@LaurencePW I have updated my answer.

thank you, now I got it.
